# who handles twitter profile of the Ask Patents?

Tags: discussion, support

Does moderator maintains twitter profile of ask patents?

https://twitter.com/AskPatents

It was not updated from last September. I am very interested to maintain the same, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The per-site Twitter feeds are/were automated based on a "hotness" algorithm or popular questions (plus some sanity checks to make sure poor or ineligible content was not broadcast). But the click-through rates on those Twitter feeds was abysmal. That, plus the fact that Twitter kept banning us for creating "too many accounts" (one for each site); we decided not to continue with that feature.

I don't think we took away the existing feeds. We just don't start new ones, nor are we considering restarting them at this time. The Ask Patents feed is currently inactive. It was generally felt that individual sites didn't really benefit from their own Twitter accounts. The fact is that bots just aren't that exciting. It sounds good on paper, but the general population is mostly uninterested in following mindless bots.

But having a human Tweeting questions ***is*** a good thing that might benefit the community a lot more than a bot ever will. If you want to re-tweet interesting questions, feel free! Just make sure the Twitter feed does not appear to be a product of Stack Exchange Inc. See our [Trademark Guidance](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

Comment: I believe instead of bot a person or moderator should take on tweet, I feel it will create a userbase with advanced reach. tweeting question is not as great as tweeting up-voted accepted answer. it bring more loyalty and appreciation to users.